# Cannot compress JPEG image and show it on screen

Tags: delphi

I try to load an image in imgQInput (which is a TImage), assign it to a TJpegImage, compress it (compression factor 5) and show it in  imgQOutput (another TImage). But it doesn't work. The image in imgQOutput is the same as the original. It should look VERY pixelated because of the compression factor! The compression works however, because when I save the JPEG to disk it is really small.

```
  JPG:= TJPEGImage.Create;
   TRY
     JPG.CompressionQuality:= trkQuality.Position;
     JPG.Assign(imgQInput.Picture.Graphic);
     CompressJpeg(JPG);
     imgQOutput.Picture.Assign(JPG);          <--------- something wrong here. the shown image is not the compressed image but the original one
   FINALLY
     FreeAndNil(JPG);
   END;


function CompressJpeg(OutJPG: TJPEGImage): Integer;
VAR tmpQStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
 tmpQStream:= TMemoryStream.Create;
 TRY
   OutJPG.Compress;
   OutJPG.SaveToStream(tmpQStream);
   OutJPG.SaveToFile('c:\CompTest.jpg');       <--------------- this works
   Result:= tmpQStream.Size;
 FINALLY
   FreeAndNil(tmpQStream);
 END;
end;
```

Comment: TJpegImage holds both bitmap DIB as well as the JPegData, even though the compress works and the save to file/stream saves the compressed JPeg, assigning it to a TImage.Picture uses the DIB instead leaving you with the original image, Vahid's answer works because he has reloaded the JPeg back from the stream, thus clearing the DIB.

Comment: Thanks Dampsquid. There is another way to do it without reloading it from stream? Like JpegNeeded or so?

Comment: I never found one, DIBNeeded only creates one if there isnt one already, and assigning to a new TJPegImage assigns the DIB too so that doesnt work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not used the compressed JPG at all.

Change `CompressJpeg` as followings:

```
function CompressJpeg(OutJPG: TJPEGImage): Integer;
VAR tmpQStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
 tmpQStream:= TMemoryStream.Create;
 TRY
   OutJPG.Compress;
   OutJPG.SaveToStream(tmpQStream);
   OutJPG.SaveToFile('c:\CompTest.jpg');    // You can remove this line.
   tmpQStream.Position := 0;                //
   OutJPG.LoadFromStream(tmpQStream);       // Reload the jpeg stream to OutJPG
   Result:= tmpQStream.Size;
 FINALLY
   FreeAndNil(tmpQStream);
 END;
end;
```

Comment: You're welcome. When you compress/save a TJpegImage instance it does not affect the original buffer. So you need to reload `OutJPG` with the newly created jpeg stream to update the buffer.

Comment: But when I save the OutJPG to disk, the image IS compressed. So, something was changed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, wrong, JPEG is far away from being just a *filter*. Truth is, this class is lazy enough to not perform an encoding until `JPEGNeeded`.

Comment: @DavidHeff, usual tendency, happens every time when people try to argue about things they don't understand ;-) Now you are backpedaling from **is** to **could be**, now take *your* time and read up on JPEG compression, and why it is not a stream filter. Otherwise, explain your interest, but remember the site slogan - *be specific*.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, i told you to be specific, there is nothing tricky with it besides normally unexposed to public scope method to instruct the class to lose its volative DIB data. And you are still repeating wrong info, Compress (public and well documented!) method instructs the class to perform described above vector and matrix transforms. And there is no stream.

Comment: @user Ask yourself why I bother? The documentation for the `Compress` method states: "Call Compress to compress for optimization, such as before streaming out when assigning a bitmap to a jpeg." Of course there is streaming. The answer above contains streaming. What needs explanation in your answer is the `FreeBitmap` call. Clearly I know what it is doing but it takes a bit of thinking about. With a good explanation your answer would be excellent. Anyway, I am now tidying up this comment stream that rather spoils somebody else's answer.

Comment: @Vahid - Now I get a 'JPEG error #42' on this line 'imgQOutput.Picture.Assign(JPG); '

Comment: @Altar: Works like a charm for me. In what situation did you received this error.

Comment: @Altar: That error should not happen in your example code. Error description tells `Premature end of input file`. I just happens if you have broken Jpeg stream (i.e if the source file is corrupt or you are wrongly using multi-thread compression).

Comment: @VahidNasehi, i believe thats "empty input file"

Comment: @user539484: This is the JPEG error descriptions http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/Graphics/JpegErrors.txt. It says: `42  cstrJERR_INPUT_EOF               Premature end of input file`

Comment: @VahidNasehi, this definitely old and might be outdated too. I'm referring to `jpeg_std_message_table` from linked version 6b (`JMSG_LASTMSGCODE` = 124) I've seen at least two version of JPEG implementation shipped with Delphi.

Comment: @user539484, Then we should wait til Altar specifies Delphi compiler version for precise answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a competing answer for you, with less data jugglery (remember, images can be large!)

```
type
  TJPEGExposed = class(TJPEGImage);     // unfortunately, local class declarations are not allowed

procedure TForm1.FormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  JPEGImage: TJPEGImage;
const
  jqCrappy = 1;
begin
  Image1.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(GetDeskWallpaper);

  Image2.Picture.Graphic := TJPEGImage.Create;
  JPEGImage := Image2.Picture.Graphic as TJPEGImage;    // a reference
  JPEGImage.Assign(Image1.Picture.Bitmap);
  JPEGImage.CompressionQuality := jqCrappy;    // intentionally
  JPEGImage.Compress;
  TJPEGExposed(JPEGImage).FreeBitmap;    { confer: TBitmap.Dormant }
end;
```

`TJPEGImage.FreeBitmap` disposes volatile DIB contained within TJPEGImage instance. In the illustrated case this causes class to decode recently `.Compress`'ed JPEG in response to `TImage` repainting.

Comment: What does the `FreeBitmap` part do? (confer?)

Comment: @user539484. Your answer seems good but it misses something: it doesn't tell the size of the compressed image. My function 'CompressJpeg' does this.

Comment: @user539484 - This application has leaked memory. The small block leaks are (excluding expected leaks registered by pointer):
21 - 36 bytes: TJPEGData x 2, TMemoryStream x 2
69 - 84 bytes: TJPEGImage x 2

Comment: @Altar, leaking of **one** TJPEGImage/TJPEGData pair acknowledged, others are elsewhere.